# Moving from MPMoviePlayerViewController to AVPlayer and streaming m3u8

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer, m3u8

I'm trying to switch from `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to `AVPlayer` for video playback in my implementation looks something similar to this

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/somefile.m3u8"];
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
movieController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
```

My `AVPlayer` version plays everything but the desired `m3u8` stream. It manages to find the file and the `AVPlayerViewController` shows the right file duration but hangs with an activity indication and never really starts playing.

```
NSURLComponents *comp = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:url.absoluteString];

AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:comp.URL options:nil];
AVAssetResourceLoader *loader = asset.resourceLoader;
[loader setDelegate:self queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

I have an observer on the status and it eventually plays when `AVPlayer`'s status is `ReadyToPlay`.
I can't imagine `AVPlayer` can play everything `MPMoviePlayerController` can so how would the right implementation for the `AVPlayer` version to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Like in your previous code (where you did `[movieController.moviePlayer play];`.
I think you should start your player.
`[self.player play];`.